# Signalr Message batching

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-signalr, signalrcore

I am researching a development of real time messaging with Signal R with web socket as transport.

My application will generate multiple messages at high rate and one question I came across is whether it would be a good idea to consider batching multiple messages before sending them out to the clients.
I have looked at the streaming functionality Signal R offers but I don't think it fits well in this case.

The messages will have variable sizes from just few bytes and up to kilobytes.

As I understand if messages are batched then there will be less time spent for serialization?
Of course this will depend on the serializer being used and may vary depending on message size.
Also there will be less round trips between client and server?

So the question is whether there would be performance gains by batching multiple messages before sending them out to clients.

I understand that it would be hard to give an conclusive answer but still would want to hear some ideas on the topic.

Comment: Maybe if your commands are just data models you should consider using SignalR streaming features? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: It is just data models and I did look at streaming BUT from documentation it states that the purpose of streaming is for sending fragments of data, I do understand that a single message can be considered as fragment of data but still not sure if the streaming bring the desired performance benefits, hope for an expert opinion.

Comment: If you are streaming `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` `T` can be anything that is serializable/deserializable and it will be your atomic chunk of data. So you can stream your POCO message classes, and achieve significant performance benefits. Mostly you will benefit in terms of memory allocation, you just need fixed buffer for streaming, never holding whole collection in memory. In terms of networking and CPU benefits are not so significant but there is.

Comment: Based on my observation there are cases where SignalR actually batches the messages and send them out to client in one go, can some one confirm that SignalR does this internally already ?

Comment: It is definitely true, SignalR is very optimized cause it is used on many device types included very restricted in resources.